# Interactive Script using Javascript

Tags: javascript, nodes, var

I have a script here that interacts with a form. It works fine but has a couple of hiccups before we can call it complete.

The script asks multiple questions which responds depending on what the user selects.

The order of questions are as follows:

Name, Bedrooms, Stories, Style.

I have two problems.

1) You can skip the first input field without entering a name. I need to make sure the user enters a name.

2) I get an invalid response when I go from Stories > Styles. Why?

If I could get some help that would be great.

Cheers

```
window.addEventListener('load', function()
{
// Create our node store, allowing us easy access to the nodes in the future.
var nodes = {};

nodes.consultant = document.querySelector('#consultant');

nodes.scope = nodes.consultant.querySelector('.col');

nodes.response = nodes.scope.querySelector('.consultant-response');
nodes.question = nodes.scope.querySelector('.consultant-question');
nodes.input = nodes.scope.querySelector('.consultant-input-wrap');
nodes.image = nodes.consultant.querySelector('.consultant-image');
nodes.dots = nodes.scope.querySelector('.consultant-dots');

var clientName = '';

// This variable will store the current question.
var question;

// Create our question store, we will iterate through these by shifting the
// first item off and replacing the question variable with it. Once the 
// client has responded to the question, it will be pushed in the responses
// store below.
var questions = [

    {
        name: 'name',
        question: 'Let’s start now. You know my name. What’s yours?',
        image: 'consultant-introduction.png',
        input: (function()
        {
            var form = document.createElement('form');

            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.placeholder = 'Enter your name';
            input.className = 'consultant-input';
            form.appendChild(input);

            var submit = document.createElement('button');
            submit.className = 'fa fa-chevron-right';
            form.appendChild(submit);

            return form;
        })(),
        response: function(name)
        {
            if (typeof name === 'undefined')
            {
                return;
            }

            question.image = 'consultant-bedroom-question.png';
            clientName = name;
            return "Hey " + name + ". Great to meet you. I’ve got a couple of questions about the new home you want to build.";
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'bedrooms',
        question: "How many bedrooms would you like?",
        input: document.querySelector('[name="_sfm_bedrooms[]"]').cloneNode(true),
        original: document.querySelector('[name="_sfm_bedrooms[]"]'),
        response: function(bedrooms)
        {
            if (typeof bedrooms === 'undefined')
            {
                return;
            }
            var response = '';

            switch (+bedrooms)
            {
                case 5:
                    response = "Five! Sounds like you need plenty of room for the family and a guest or three.";
                    question.image = 'consultant-five-bedroom-answer.png';
                    break;
                case 4:
                    response = "4 bedrooms, great! We’ve got plenty of ideas for you already.";
                    question.image = 'consultant-four-bedroom-answer.png';
                    break;
                case 3:
                    response = "Brilliant, 3 bedrooms. We love smaller but perfectly formed homes too.";
                    question.image = 'consultant-three-bedroom-answer.png';
                    break;
                default:
                    response = "Well that isn't a valid response...";
                    question.image = '';
            }

            return response;
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'levels',
        question: function(bedrooms)
        {
            if (typeof bedrooms === 'undefined')
            {
                return;
            }

            var question = '';

            switch (+bedrooms)
            {
                case 5:
                    question = "Does that mean you want two storeys as well or would you rather spread out over one?";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    question = "How high would you like to go? One or two storeys?";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    question = "Does that mean you’re after a single storey home or two levels maybe? ";
                    break;
                default:
            }

            return question;
        },
        input: document.querySelector('[name="_sfm_levels[]"]').cloneNode(true),
        original: document.querySelector('[name="_sfm_levels[]"]'),
        response: function(levels)
        {
            var response = '';

            switch (+levels)
            {
                case 2:
                    response = "Thanks " + clientName + ", two storeys will give you a lot of flexibility.";
                    question.image = 'consultant-two-storey-answer.png';
                    break;
                case 1:
                    response = "Nice " + clientName + ", a single storey home is a great option.";
                    question.image = 'consultant-one-storey-answer.png';
                    break;
                default:
                    response = "Well that isn't a valid response...";
                    question.image = '';
            }

            return response;
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'style',
        question: "I’ve got one more question, do you like contemporary or traditional style homes?",
        image: 'consultant-style-answer.png',
        input: document.querySelector('[name="_sfm_style[]"]').cloneNode(true),
        original: document.querySelector('[name="_sfm_style[]"]'),
        response: function(style)
        {
            var response = '';

            switch (style)
            {
                case 'Traditional':
                    response = "You can’t beat the classics eh! Brilliant, check out a few ideas we think you’ll like below.";
                    break;
                case 'Modern':
                    response = "Great, you’re after something a little more modern. Check out a few ideas we think you’ll like below.";
                    break;
                default:
                    response = "Well that isn't a valid response...";
                    question.image = '';
            }

            return response;
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'done',
        question: "Remember, these plans are just a starting point. We can completely customise any of them to suit your needs perfectly.",
        input: (function()
        {
            var wrap = document.createElement('div');
            wrap.className = 'consultant-done-wrap';

            var elmnt = document.createElement('a');
            elmnt.className = 'consultant-done fa fa-angle-down';
            elmnt.href = "#find-a-plan";
            wrap.appendChild(elmnt);

            return wrap;
        })()
    }
];

// Once a client responds to a question, that question object will be added
// to this array.
var responses = [];

// Create our function store, this helps organize our functions, but also
// prevents conflict with existing function names.
var funcs = {};

// Prompt the user with the new question.
funcs.prompt = function(e)
{
    // Cancel the default event if an event object is supplied
    if (typeof e !== 'undefined' && typeof e.preventDefault === 'function')
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    // Store the previous response if it is available, so that we can pass
    // it to the question function.
    var previous = {};

    if (typeof question !== 'undefined')
    {
        if (question.input instanceof HTMLElement)
        {
            // If the input field is a form element, we have to search for 
            // the input element.
            if (/form/i.test(question.input.tagName))
            {
                previous.value = question.input.querySelector('input').value;
            }
            else
            {
                previous.value = question.input.value;
            }

            // If there was no selected value, or the value is empty, stop here
            if (typeof previous === 'undefined' || previous.length === 0)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        // Check if the response field is supplied
        if (typeof question.response !== 'undefined')
        {
            if (typeof question.response === 'function')
            {
                // If the response is a function, call it with the value of the input,
                // and apply the output to the response node.
                nodes.response.innerHTML = question.response(previous.value);
            }
            else
            {
                // If it isn't a function, apply the value to the response node.
                nodes.response.innerHTML = question.response;
            }

            // Push the current question onto the response array.
            responses.push(question);

            // Remove the current input element.
            nodes.input.removeChild(question.input);
        }

        // Just a check to make sure the dot element is actually an element,
        // safety first!
        if (question.dot instanceof HTMLElement)
        {
            // Set the dot for the current question as active.
            question.dot.className += ' active';
        }

        previous.question = question;
    }

    // Assign the new question to the current question variable.
    // This removes the first question from the question store.
    question = questions.shift();

    // If we are on the first question, load the image for this question.
    if (typeof previous.question === 'undefined')
    {
        previous.question = question;
    }

    // If there is an image attached to the previous question, show it.
    // This is usually set in the response field, so we can know what the response was.
    if (typeof previous.question.image !== 'undefined')
    {
        if (nodes.image instanceof HTMLElement)
        {
            nodes.image.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + previous.question.image + ')';
        }
    }

    // Check to see if the question field is set.
    if (typeof question.question !== 'undefined')
    {
        if (typeof question.question === 'function')
        {
            // If the question is a function, call it and apply the output 
            // to the question node.
            nodes.question.innerHTML = question.question(previous.value);
        }
        else
        {
            // If it isn't a function, apply the value to the question node.
            nodes.question.innerHTML = question.question;
        }
    }

    // Check if the input field is an HTML element
    if (question.input instanceof HTMLElement)
    {
        // If it is, insert it into the input container.
        nodes.input.appendChild(question.input);
    }

    // Check to see if we are on the last question or not.
    if (question.name !== 'done')
    {
        // If not, check if the input element is an HTML element
        if (question.input instanceof HTMLElement)
        {
            // Make sure the input element isn't actually a form element.
            if (!/form/i.test(question.input.tagName))
            {
                // Apply the styling to the input element.
                question.input.className += ' consultant-input';

                // Apply the event listener to the input element.
                question.input.addEventListener('change', funcs.prompt, false);
            }
            else
            {
                // Apply the event listener to the input element.
                question.input.addEventListener('submit', funcs.prompt, false);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // If we are on the last question, remove the dots and update the originals.
        nodes.scope.removeChild(nodes.dots);
        funcs.updateAllInputs();
    }

};
// Update an individual input.
funcs.updateInput = function(response)
{
    // If no original element was passed, exit the function
    if (typeof response.original === 'undefined')
    {
        return;
    }

    // Check to see if the original field is actually an HTML element.
    if (response.original instanceof HTMLElement)
    {
        // Set the value of the original input to that of the client input.
        response.original.value = response.input.value;

        // This is because IE is stupid. We have to check if "fireEvent" is a function.
        if ("fireEvent" in document)
        {
            // If it is, the user is browsing with IE, use the "fireEvent" function
            response.original.fireEvent('onchange');
        }
        else
        {
            // If it isn't, the user is browsing with a real browser.
            // Create a "change" event.
            var event = new UIEvent("change",
            {
                "view": window,
                "bubbles": true,
                "cancelable": true
            });

            // Dispatch the "change" event
            response.original.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
    }
};

// Update all of the inputs.
funcs.updateAllInputs = function()
{
    // Iterate through the responses array.
    for (var i in responses)
    {
        // This excludes the "length" field, only relevant on mobile devices.
        if (responses.hasOwnProperty(i))
        {
            // Update the original input.
            funcs.updateInput(responses[i]);
        }
    }
};

// Make the dots to show the progress through the consultant
funcs.makeDots = function()
{
    // Iterate through the questions array.
    for (var i in questions)
    {
        // This excludes the "length" field, only relevant on mobile devices.
        if (questions.hasOwnProperty(i))
        {
            // Skip the last question.
            if (questions[i].name === 'done')
            {
                continue;
            }

            // Make the dot
            questions[i].dot = document.createElement('li');

            // Append the dot to the dots container
            nodes.dots.appendChild(questions[i].dot);
        }
    }
};

// Make the dots.
funcs.makeDots();

// Prompt the first question.
funcs.prompt();
}, false);
```

HTML

```
<section class="beige section-padding strip-wrap" id="consultant">
    <div class="container entry clr">
        <div class="clr col span_1_of_3 col-1">
            <h1 class="red">Can I help?</h1>
            <div class="white consultant-response">
                Hi, I'm Glenda. Our job is to make your build as easy and tailored as possible.
            </div>
            <div class="orange consultant-question"></div>
            <div class="consultant-input-wrap"></div>
            <ul class="consultant-dots"></ul>

        </div>
        <div class="clr col span_2_of_3"></div>
        <a href="#find-a-plan">
            <div class="strip">These homes are a perfect starting point
                <div class="strip-arrow"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <!-- .entry-content -->
    <div class="consultant-showcase">
        <div class="consultant-image">
            <div class="consultant-introduction"></div>
            <div class="consultant-bedroom-question"></div>
            <div class="consultant-three-bedroom-answer"></div>
            <div class="consultant-four-bedroom-answer"></div>
            <div class="consultant-five-bedroom-answer"></div>
            <div class="consultant-one-storey-answer"></div>
            <div class="consultant-two-storey-aswer"></div>
            <div class="consultant-style-answer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: _"1) You can skip the first input field without entering a name."_ Use `required` attribute. Can you include `html` at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 - Where should the required attribute be placed?

Comment: `var input = document.createElement("input"); input.setAttribute("required", true)`

Comment: @guest271314 like so: var input = document.createElement('input');
                input.placeholder = 'Enter your name';
                input.className = 'consultant-input';
    input.className("required", true);
                form.appendChild(input);

Comment: No. Not `className`, `required` attribute

Comment: @guest271314 - thanks, works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) You can skip the first input field without entering a name. I need
>   to make sure the user enters a name.

Use [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required) attribute at `input` or `select` elements.

Comment: Problem 2. Why do you think this happens?

Comment: @tebrown Difficult to determine without `html`. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . What is "Stories"?

Comment: @tebrown _"Where should I post the html?"_ At original Question . See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have included `html`. Cheers.